# NPM linking a scoped module

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am attempting to make some small modifications to a scoped package in the **node_modules** directory of a React app. I have followed the necessary procedure for linking: 'npm link' in the package directory and then 'npm link @packagename' in the app root directory.

I'm currently getting the following npm error:

> npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME
>   npm ERR! Invalid tag name "@packagename": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.

It it possible to locally link scoped packages or is this a system bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do it, but "`@packagename`" isn't a package name, it's a scope only. You should be able to directly link any packages in that scope by `@scope/packagename` - you might have to do this a few times.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks much. Had to run the commands as a superuser for some reason but it work perfectly!